# Play sound when each time app is launched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a convenient way to play a sound when the app is launched? 
I want it to be played *only* when the app is launched, not when the app entered background and went out of a background state.

Any ideas where I could put the code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your sound code to

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

That method is only called once, when the app first opens.

Answer (score 3):

In your app delegate in the function...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```